# Graph coloring all possible solutions, special case

Tags: java, arrays, graph-coloring

I am trying to solve a problem where I have a grid. say *`(3xn)`*. Using **3** colours. I want to the number of all possible solutions. Adjacent cells of the grid can have the same colour. the only restriction is that: 
 **`No one single row or column can have all cells having the same colour.`**
 How best can I solve this for atmost about 25000 columns ?

I solved the one where no adjacent cells should have the same colour. And for 3 rows and 2 columns that gave 54 solutions.
where I just altered the code from [this site](http://satybald.com/dynamic/programming/2017/09/24/ways-to-color-3xN-board/)
and just check the edge cases.

for example the bottom end:

```
boolean isBottomOk(int r, int c, int n)  {
    if(r == numberOfRows - 1) return true;
    if(grid[r + 1][c] != n) return true;
    return false;
}
```

And finally solve it like:

```
 void solve(int r, int c)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfColors; i++)
        {   
            if(valid(r, c, i))
            {
                grid[r][c] = i;
                if(r == numberOfRows - 1 && c == numberOfColumns - 1) 
                {
                    printBoard();
                    numberOfCombinations++;
                }
                else if(r == numberOfRows - 1) solve(0, c + 1);
                else solve(r + 1, c);
            }
        }
        grid[r][c] = 0;
    }

    boolean valid(int r, int c, int n)
    {
        return(isLeftOk(r, c, n) && isRightOk(r, c, n) &&  isTopOk(r, c, n) &&  isBottomOk(r, c, n));
    }
```

As a result. I expect to have a solution that works for all `3xn` grids with utmost 25000 columns using 3 colors.

Comment: For `n=2`, the solution count of `54` seems too small. If I brute-force all possible states, I get `174` solutions (see [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/vgSeWkAh), with the colors being encoded with `0`, `1`, `2`). Also, the number of solutions growth exponentially, so I would expect e.g. a 64-bit solution counter to overflow rather quickly (way before reaching `n=25000`). So I'm wondering how you intend to handle this case (.e.g using `BigInteger`?). I think it would be helpful if you would elaborate on the `54` solution you gave and what data type you intend to use for the solution counter.